# Wordpress post not showing inside images

Tags: wordpress, web, wordpress-theming

I have a new website built on latest Wordpress. My issue is in posts, its not showing images automatically when I scroll through, but when I move mouse pointer, its showing a magnifying glass (means there is an image below) and when I click on it, image is come-up on top but not on the post. It looks like only if the image is bigger than the area in post, its doing this because I can see images on other posts where image is smaller.

One example of a post that has issue:

https://www.techadrive.com/hp-envy-curved-all-in-one-34-review-stylish-sophistication-in-a-pc/

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you all.

Comment: How are you including the image in a wordpress post? Could you post the code in the backend of the page. There might be something there that is triggering this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your Image path is wrong:

Your site image path is: data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7

actual image path is: https://icdn7.digitaltrends.com/image/digitaltrends/hp-envy-curved-34-review-9-1500x1000.jpg

You can add image again and add the same path in your website section.
Make sure Your Problem is solved